# Iterate code for every 200n entries to a time series Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

Forgive my ignorance, am new to coding or have never had much reason to do it, and do not know what to look for. Have tried Googling my question and could not find an answer or syntax with explanations included.

I have data that looks like this:

[image]

Where "time" ranges from 100 to 400 ns, for every replica of the simulation ranging from 0 to 19. The cluster label for each time point can be a number from 1 - 100.

What I need are the are the sum() of each cluster element from time = 100, for every 1 ns of time.

Ideally, I will have an array that looks like this:

[image]

Where the columns indicate cluster population at given time increments, and the zeros indicate cluster populations of 0 after 0 ns sampling, and the cluster populations will increase at every 1 ns increment.

What I have been able to do is write a code that sums all cluster populations for the entire time period of that replica.

```
import numpy as np

req_columns = pd.read_csv('data.dat', usecols=['Replica','frame','cluster']).dropna(how='all')
req_columns = req_columns.drop(req_columns[req_columns.Replica == ' '].index)
req_columns = req_columns.drop(req_columns[req_columns.cluster == ' '].index)
req_columns = req_columns.astype(dtype = {'Replica':np.int32, 'frame':np.int32, 'cluster':np.int32})

for replica in range(0,20): #counter used to iterate through all replica 
        replica_iter = req_columns[req_columns['Replica'] == replica]
        replica_iter.reset_index(inplace=True) # we need to reset index as we use index to iterate 
        clusters = replica_iter['cluster']
        
        for clusterLabel in range(1,101):
                print(replica, clusterLabel, sum(clusters == clusterLabel))
```

How do I get the code to do this for 1 ns increments? Specifically, how do I get the code to count cluster populations at 100 ns, 101 ns, 102 ns, 103 ns ... 400 ns. Every 1 ns increment is 200 frames.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Looks like a `pivot_table`, or maybe a `rolling` but it's difficult to be sure without a clear reproducible example